# How do I determine which path my application is run from?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm creating a little program to copy the Domain file for iWeb over to a USB stick or external harddrive or such. The program is meant to be run from that USB stick or external harddrive, and then create a directory where the application is run from. E.g. the application is run from ~/Documents, the application should create a folder at ~/Documents/(account name)'s website, and then copy the Domain file to that folder. But when I try to run the application from a USB stick, it creates a folder under /, called /(account name)'s website. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the current working directory of your app then use NSFileManager's currentDirectoryPath.

```
NSString *currentPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSBundle` has an instance method called [`bundlePath`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_20) which will almost get you what you want.

```
NSString *bundleParentPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

This should return the directory that the application is being run from.

Comment: No, it'll return the path to the bundle.